# X and Y have joint density function c/x^3

Tags: probability

Suppose X and Y have joint density function:

\begin{equation}
f (x,y) =
\begin{cases}
 c/x^3& \text{} x < y < 1\\
0  &\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where c is a constant.

a) find c. ,
b) find the marginal density of X ,
c) what is the conditional distribution of Y given X = x?

For a), I know that I have to apply:

\begin{equation}
1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dxdy
\end{equation}

Otherwise, I'm struggling to get started. Any hints and helps are appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hint: $f_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{XY}(x,y) \mathrm{d}y$. Part c follows from Bayes' rule.

Comment: Also, they tell you that $x<y<1$, so the bounds on the integral are not literally infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of it in this way: to get a non-zero integrand, $y$ must be between $-\infty$ and $1$ and once we choose $y$, $x$ must be between $-\infty$ and $y$ so your integral becomes

$$ 1 =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy = \int_{-\infty}^1\int_{-\infty}^y \frac{c}{x^3} dx dy$$

Solving the integral, we get

$$ \int_{-\infty}^1\int_{-\infty}^y \frac{c}{x^3} dx dy = \int_{-\infty}^1 \left[ -\frac{c}{2x^2}\right]_{-\infty}^y dy =  -\int_{-\infty}^1 \frac{c}{2y^2} dy = \left[ \frac{c}{2y}\right]_{-\infty}^1 = \frac{c}{2} $$

so that

$$ c=2 $$

Comment: I'm looking at it now, but I'm still a little bit loss..

Comment: Can you solve the integral above?

Comment: I think I've done it wrong, since the answer from maple/calculus gave a undef.

Comment: I've got -1/2*cy/x^2

Comment: okay... I've got: 1=-cy/2
So c = -2/y?

Comment: The answer will be a constant independent of $x$ and $y$. You need to substitute in the limits $(-\infty, y)$ after performing the first integration, then integrate the second time. If you're still having trouble I can expand my answer a bit later.

Comment: I think I need your help -_-"

Comment: Okay, I've expanded out the answer to show how the integral is done.

Comment: THANK YOU! That's a lot of help.. 
I am now looking at b) and a little bit confused on which limits I've to apply for the integral

Comment: I have to apply this marginal density of X right? But which limits should it be? 
\begin{equation}
f_X(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dy = \int_{-\infty}^{y} 2/x^3 dy = \left[ -\frac{1}{x^2}\right]_{-\infty}^y
\end{equation}

Comment: So, you're essentially fixing $x$ and integrating with respect to $y$. The integrand is non-zero only when $x<y<1$ so the limits are $x$ (lower) and $1$ (upper). Also, if you integrate $2/x^3$ with respect to $y$ you get $2y/x^3$

Comment: \begin{equation} f_X(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dy = \int_{x}^{1} 2/x^3 dy = \frac{2(1-x)}{x^3} \end{equation}

Comment: Yes, exactly. and remember, this only holds for $x < 1$. For $x \ge 1$ we get $0$.

Comment: Thank you!
Can you help with c) too? How should I get started? :)

Comment: Is there any relationship between this conditional distribution and the the answers you found so far? I would start from there.

Comment: So this much be the relationship:
\begin{equation}
f_{YlX}(ylx)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}
\end{equation}
first I have to know what the marginal density of Y is:
\begin{equation} f_Y(y)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dx 
 \end{equation}
right? but then again.. the limits?

Comment: You don't need the marginal density of $Y$, see your top equation. You're just dividing the first answer by the second, You just have to be careful to specify for what values of $y$ this is non-zero.

Comment: so you mean that it should be:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2/x^3}{2(1-x)/x^3}
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes but only for $x<y<1$, otherwise it's $0$. A good exercise to check for all these distributions is that if you integrate over the entire range, you get $1$.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!!! :D